# CSS for Vertical Woocommerce Gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

On my [web page](https://unlatino.com/producto/banc-ecole/), I am changing the default woocommerce gallery to a vertical view. I use two columns of 70% gallery, 30% text. I tried the following CSS code, but I still need to make the thumbnails a bit bigger and move the main photo to the right, as I show in the [attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj9ld.jpg)
Could you guide me with a little more code?
Thanks!

```css
.woocommerce-product-gallery {
    display: flex;}
.woocommerce-product-gallery .flex-control-thumbs {
    order: -10;}
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;}
.woocommerce div.product .product_meta {
    border-top: 0px solid #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: 0 0 .8em;}
.woocommerce div.product div.images img {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
ol.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs { width: 100%; }

img.wp-post-image { margin-left: 50px; }
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't look right, there is a lot of empty space in the main photo. Maybe I should clear my code and accept a full suggestion.
Here is a clear [https://terre-et-metal.fr/product/479/banc-ecole] example of what it should look like

Answer (score 0):

It could slightly differ depending on your installation but this works for me:

```
    .single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex- 
    viewport {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
    }

    /* Make Gallery 25% width and place it beside the image */

    .single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex- 
    control-thumbs {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    }

    /* Style each Thumbnail with width and margins */

    .single-product div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery .flex- 
    control-thumbs li img {
    width: 90%;
    float: none;
    margin: -10px 0 0 10%;
    }
```